# How to move certain directories under few parent directories one level up in unix

Tags: unix, mv

I have

```
A/1/a
A/1/b

B/1/a
B/1/b
```

all these are folders. I am trying to move the directories so that it may look like

```
A/a
A/b

B/a
B/b
```

I am sure I should use `mv` command but I am not sure to do it for all the directories at once.

Answer (score 1):

Not in one go, but since we're not code golfing:

```
 mv A/1/* A; rmdir A/1
 mv B/1/* B; rmdir B/1
```

The canonical gotchas apply, like `*` not globbing dot files, depending on shell options. You'll know when you run into them when you see `rmdir: directory not empty`.